# Not understanding how this solution for obtaining min value in list of lists works

Tags: python, list

I have the current list of lists:

```python
item1 = [3.00, 'Item1']
item2 = [4.50, 'Item2']
item3 = [5.00, 'Item3']
item4 = [2.00, 'Item4']

items = [item1, item2, item3, item4]
```

I want to find the list with the smallest float value. Here is how I'm finding it:

```python
minitem = min(min(item[0:]) for item in items)
```

I understand what it's doing, but I'm not understanding the syntax (or how to read it).

I naturally put `item[0]` in the inner `min()` call, because that would be referring to the first position in the list which is a float, but I got "`TypeError, 'float' object is not iterable`".

I don't get why I have to specify a range for the inner `min()` call when it's only the first spot in the list I'm calculating the minimum value on.

Comment: `minitem = min(item[0] for item in items)` is a simplified version

Comment: You have to specify a range because of the `min(item[0:])` min() requires a list input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look:

```
minitem = min(min(item[0:]) for item in items)
```

`item[0:]` is the same as simply `item` (you are slicing from the first element to the last).

Computing `min(item[0:]) for item in items` is a bit iffy in that it returns the smaller of `3.00` and  `'Item1'`, the smaller of `4.50` and `'Item2'`, and so on. This happens to do what you want (return the float rather than the string), but by a fluke.

Finally, the outer `min()` returns the smallest of the floats.

Here is how I would write it:

```
In [7]: min(item[0] for item in items)
Out[7]: 2.0
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a simpler solution. One question: What if there was item5 = [2.00, 'Item5']? I'm assuming it would return the first instance of the list that has the smallest value. Is there anyway I could return both items?

Comment: @foadster: To return all items you first need to find out the minimum, and then select all items that have the same value as the minimum.

Comment: Yeah, I already did that. Just thought there may be a simpler solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use of key is better here:

```
>>> item1 = [3.00, 'Item1']
>>> item2 = [4.50, 'Item2']
>>> item3 = [5.00, 'Item3']
>>> item4 = [2.00, 'Item4']
>>> items = [item1, item2, item3, item4]
>>> min(items,key=lambda x:x[0])  
[2.0, 'Item4']
```

or simply:

```
>>> min(items)
[2.0, 'Item4']
```

Comment: How does min know to return the list with the smallest float value if you are just passing in a list of floats and strings?

Comment: by default min , only evaluates on 1st element of sublist

Answer (score 0):

The [`min()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) returns the minimum of its positional arguments, or of the members of the iterable given as the only positional argument. You can also specify a function to extract a comparable value from each sorted object with the `key` keyword argument.

Your current form uses a generator expression to create a new series by taking the minimum of each item (`min(item[0:])`). Numbers are always "less than" strings, so after this first step, your statement is equivalent to:

```
min(3.0, 4.5, 5.0, 2.0)
```

Which is straightforwardly `2.0`.

There are several simpler forms you could use to make this easier to understand.

- You could use list comparison to compare the items directly, then take the first element of the result. This is the shortest, but could yield different results if the structure of the items changes in the future:

  ```
  min(items)[0]
  ```
- You could use the `key` keyword argument to extract the comparable value from each item, then take the first element of the result. This is a little complicated, but the idea could work well if you actually want the whole item in the end (i.e. without the `[0]` at the end):

  ```
  min(items, key=lambda x: x[0])[0]
  ```
- You could extract the comparable element from each item in a generator expression, then take the minimum of that. This is probably the most straightforward way to get just the minimum number, but is harder to modify to get different results (i.e. the name of the smallest item):

  ```
  min(item[0] for item in items)
  ```